# Reset EmbeddedKafka After Every Test Method

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am writing a test class that has multiple methods that require Kafka. Each one requires different broker properties, so I want a separate instance of EmbeddedKafka for each. Doing

```
@EmbeddedKafka(
    partitions = 20,
    topics = {"topic"},
    controlledShutdown = false,
    brokerProperties = {
      "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9091",
      "port=9091",
      "auto.create.topics.enable=false",
      "delete.topic.enable=true"
    })
```

Uses the broker properties for each method in the class. I don't want this. One way to overcome this would be to put each test method in a separate class with different broker properties. But I don't want to do this, as this would blow up the number of files I need.

Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's better to use different topics in each test. However, you can add `@DirtiesContext` to each test method or add `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` to the test class.

Comment: This solution slows down tests considerably. Any alternative without recreating the context?

Comment: I tried to delete the topics before each test but after a while I end up getting: Expected 3 but got 0 partitions
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected 3 but got 0 partitions
 at org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.ContainerTestUtils.waitForSingleContainerAssignment(ContainerTestUtils.java:115)

any ideas why?